# issue with the Authorisation: Bearer access_token (the headers) in Axios POST in reacts

Tags: reactjs, laravel, fetch

I am trying to create a login from the end point which uses authorisation and bearer access_token. I don't know to properly pass the token to the authorisation in the header and hence the following error occurs.

Response {type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}

I have tried to read up Axios post and grant type to see how I can pass the access_token to the bearer. The problem is the token is generated during the sign_up per user. How do I get to use it in the login. 
The image from the postman to illustrate. I copied the access_token generated from sign up to the authorisation.

[image]

```
handleLogin(event){
      event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("password", this.state.l_password);
        formData.append("email",this.state.l_email);
        formData.append("remember_me", true);
      fetch('api/auth/login',
         {
            headers:{
               // 'accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'content-type': 'application/json',
                'authorization': 'bearer',
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            method: "POST",
            body:formData

         }
      )
           .then(response => {
                console.log(response);

            })
            .then(json => {
                return json.json();

            })
        }
```

From Postman, I am using only content-type:  application/json as header to login. But what baffled most is, it is showing status: ok and it is not actually working.

[image]

Comment: I tried to use fetchapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it slightly wrong. First, you have to consider the API uses token which needs to be specified in your endpoint such as **/oauth/token**. 
First, if you have postman, try to test http://localhost:port/oauth/token then specify the header content-type:application/json and in your body, do something like this: -

```
{
    "username": "something@yahoo.com", 
    "password" : "abcdef",
    "client_id": "4",
    "client_secret" :"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "grant_type": "password",
    "scope": "*"
}
```

If you look closely at the code, I have below, you can see I made everything into the body.

However, I have rewritten your code

```
handleLogin(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      fetch('/oauth/token',
         {
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },

            body:`grant_type=password&username=${this.state.username}&password=${this.state.l_password}&client_id=4&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&scope=*`

         }
      )
      .then(response =>
        response.json()
      )
      .then(responseJson => {
          const returnObj = responseJson;
          console.log(returnObj);
      })
```

To read more [enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/adiachenko/e4c671ee5ba372febfd5c5bb9baba1fe)
another resources [enter link description here](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-27.html#rfc.section.4.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can store the token in localstorage, and make some mecanisme to verify if the user is logged in.

here is an article who covers the entire prosess https://medium.com/@romanchvalbo/how-i-set-up-react-and-node-with-json-web-token-for-authentication-259ec1a90352

Comment: Thanks but I am using Laravel Passport and ReactJs